# xampp configuration in windows server 2008 r2 ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp, cloud, ec2-ami

i am trying to set up a site with xampp. i have succesfully connected to the instance via remote desktop and installed xampp and python (needed for my php script). now i am trying to find a way to connect to the instance's localhost via a browser in my local computer with the provided private and elastic IPs but no succefull attempt yet. i would like to configure that with a static IP or domain name (i suppose the elastic or private IP?) because my site will be used for http requests.

Answer (score 1):

- did you allow port 80/443 in your security group?
- did you start the xampp server?
- when logged in via remote desktop, are you able the open 'http://localhost' in a remote browser?
- your elastic IP is the address reachable from public
- private IP is the address reachable from within the availability zone